# what happens if I don't fight Nybeth in chapter one?

Tags: tactics-ogre-psp

In Tactics Ogre: LUCT what happens if I don't fight Nybeth in chapter one?

Are there any implications if I opt not to fight him in chapter one?

What about if I do and defeat him?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what option you choose when talking to Nybeth in Chapter One.  Either way, you have to fight him.  The option you choose makes no difference in the fight; he still summons the same units.

He's a reoccurring character you'll encounter throughout the game.  No matter what options you choose, he won't join you, and you'll probably fight him at least a few more times.

You do eventually get to kill him, but even that doesn't stop him entirely.

Comment: So if I don't fight him at all in chapter one then it doesn't affect anything?

Comment: Not a single thing.  It's an optional fight, and you'll run into him more later on.